# CAML error: "One or more field types are not installed properly."

Tags: caml-query

I'm using the U2U CAML Query Builder tool and no matter what I do, I can't create a query. It keeps generating the error: `One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.0x81020014`

If I just right-click on the list and do GetListItems, it works fine and returns results. By the way, it even throws the error when trying to create a query with the built-in Announcements list. Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Here's a sample one for the Announcements list that also throws the same error:

```
<Query>
   <Where>
      <Or>
         <IsNotNull>
            <FieldRef Name='Title' />
         </IsNotNull>
      </Or>
   </Where>
</Query>
<ViewFields>
   <FieldRef Name='ID' />
   <FieldRef Name='Title' />
   <FieldRef Name='Modified' />
   <FieldRef Name='Created' />
   <FieldRef Name='Author' />
   <FieldRef Name='Editor' />
   <FieldRef Name='_UIVersionString' />
   <FieldRef Name='Attachments' />
   <FieldRef Name='Body' />
   <FieldRef Name='Expires' />
</ViewFields>
<QueryOptions />
```

Comment: Does it throw an error in the Query builder? Or when using your query in sharepoint? Like Alexander said, you should delete the <Or> and </Or> tags

Comment: It was the unneeded `<Or>`. Thanks, RubenHerman :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the `<or>` or add a second clause to the `<or>`. In SharePoint CAML-queries you must have two (and only two) clauses in an `<or>` or `<and>` section.

In the U2U-Camlbuilder you can generate it like this: (Notice that `filter` is selected )
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Dribbel. That was it! But the error is so confusing I didn't realize my mistake.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you should remove < Or > tag or add the second fild to the expression